# Does the coin support HD wallets, and if so, which derivation scheme?

Tags: sub-address, wallet

Can you tell me which derivation scheme is used in Monero, as BIP32/44 is well defined for ECDSA only and not for EdDSA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin's HD (hierarchical deterministic) wallets use subsequent addresses derived from your private key / seed to send your change to and improve privacy *a bit*. You can still follow the funds and determine eg. from spending patterns or known destinations what actually was the spending amount(s) and what the change.

Monero's design focussed on mandatory privacy is completely different and a plain address **never lands on the blockchain**, a spender calculates a one time stealth address from the receivers public key / address and a random number. Only the receiver with his private key is able to determine, that an output is for him.

However, one can generate unlimited "HD" addresses which are called **Subadresses** in Monero which are generated similar to Bitcoin's HD addresses if you don't want to be linked externally eg. by different exchanges or your employer and your donation address on social media.

Comment: @Bart thanks for your feedback! please mark it as "correct answer" if you don't need any more details.